# "Content is not allowed in prolog" error when trying to connect to FCM XMPP endpoint with Smack library

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, smack

Im trying to create Server to connect to Firebase XMPP endpoint to receive upstream messages. Im using Java Openfire Smack library. When i try to connect to the endpoint i receive error provided down below.

I have tried to find some examples of how to connect to the Firebase XMPP endpoint, but they were outdated.

**MY CONNECTION BUILDER**

```
private static final String fcmServer = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
private static final int fcmPort = 5236;
private static final String fcmSenderId = "101010101010@fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
private static final String fcmApiKey = "XYZ";
private XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration configuration;
private XMPPTCPConnection connection;

    public XmppClientModule() {
        try {
            configuration = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(fcmSenderId, fcmApiKey)
                    .setXmppDomain("PROJECT_ID.fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com")
                    .setHost(fcmServer)                                            
                    .setPort(fcmPort)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible)
                    .build();

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error handling");
        }

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            connection.connect();
            connection.login();
            System.out.println("Connected successfully");
        } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$SmackWrappedException: org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.XmlPullParserException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.setCurrentConnectionExceptionAndNotify(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:687)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.notifyConnectionError(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:987)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$4100(XMPPTCPConnection.java:131)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1167)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$700(XMPPTCPConnection.java:916)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:939)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.XmlPullParserException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Caused by: org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.XmlPullParserException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]

Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.stax.StaxXmlPullParser.next(StaxXmlPullParser.java:193)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1143)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]

Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.stax.StaxXmlPullParser.next(StaxXmlPullParser.java:191)
    ... 4 more
```

**Dependencies**
I also tried to use
`implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-xmlparser-xpp3:4.4.6'`
but i received same error differently paraphrased

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2'

    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.4.6'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.4.6'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.4.6'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-xmlparser-stax:4.4.6'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.4.6'
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the Smack Library is compatible with Firebase XMPP?  I know the library works with the XMPP server software (Openfire) also made by Jive Software.

Comment: I dont see reason why it wouldnt be compatible. XMPP is messagging protocol like http, and it doesnt matter who owns the server. Also I saw some tickets about firebase and their library on their web.